# Avahi daemon can't launch due to dbus-daemon problems

Tags: centos, d-bus, avahi

I'm trying to run `avahi-daemon` on CentOS 6.5, but when I run it I get this error:

```
bash-4.1# avahi-daemon
Found user 'avahi' (UID 70) and group 'avahi' (GID 70).
Successfully dropped root privileges.
avahi-daemon 0.6.25 starting up.
dbus_bus_get_private(): Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
WARNING: Failed to contact D-Bus daemon.
```

I tried to follow the steps at [this blog post](http://theengguy.blogspot.com/2013/02/mdns-centos-63.html). All seemed to work as expected until this one:

```
service messagebus start
```

But even after running the system message bus (even manually with `dbus-daemon --system`) I still get the same error upon running avahi.

Comment: Try to add `enable-dbus=no` in the server section.

Comment: @DavidGatti add an answer